# Installing MonoDevelop on Suse Enterprise 10.0

Tags: linux, mono, installation, monodevelop, suse

I tried to install MonoDevelop on Suse 11.0 Enterprise, using the 1-click install on the MonoDevelop download page, but quickly wound up in a tangle of missing dependencies.  I then tried using the Suse software repositories to get MonoDevelop, and waded through several of the dependencies for awhile trying to get the necessary packages to fulfill the dependencies, but some of the packages in the Suse repositories actually appear to be missing the needed RPM files. Are these repositories no longer being actively maintained?

I am aware that there is a CD [on the Mono site](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) (called the Mono LiveCD) that appears to contain a complete installation of the development environment, as well as a DVD for OpenSuse 11.2  (on the OpenSuse site) that *might* actually have all of the Mono software already installed.  But the target environment for the utility I am writing is Suse 11.0 Enterprise Server.  Does that matter?

What is the shortest distance between two points here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that might actually have all of the Mono software already installed.

It has all of the Mono software installed ( of course it depends on what do you mean 'all') Last time when i tried it, the installation included Mono itself, monodevelop, MoMa and some software, written in Mono ( gome-do, for example ). I did not perform *any* additional steps for migrating my solution from a windows machine. the one thing worth to mention, monodevelop crashed several times, but i think it was memory-related ( an image had access only to 512 mb of RAM ).

> But the target environment for the
>   utility I am writing is Suse 11.0
>   Enterprise Server. Does that matter?

In theory, it does not. You will have to check Mono versions of course, but i don't think you will face any problems during migration process. As far as i know, Suse 11.0 comes with Mono 2.0 pre-installed. With a latest life-cd you are going to develop using mono 2.6. There were some major changes ( partial LINQ to SQL suport ) you will have to compare changelog's of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install Mono on Suse Linux Enterprise Server, you need to download the Mono Extension Pack (available [here](http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=i25FHB-8OPg~)).  In SLES 11 it was separated out into a separate product in order to decouple the support life cycle from that of the general distribution.  This allows them to release more often.

The add-on is available for x86, x86_64, and IBM System Z.